What capabilities must SpaceX develop prior to the uncrewed Starship missions to Mars in 2026 in order to enable a Mars human landing mission in 2028?
Elon Musk, the CEO and Chief Technology Officer of the world’s dominant space launch company has recently stated that in 2026 SpaceX will demonstrate the capability to land humans on Mars.

The first Starships to Mars will launch in 2 years when the next Earth-Mars transfer window opens. These will be uncrewed to test the reliability of landing intact on Mars. If those landings go well, then the first crewed flights to Mars will be in 4 years.

Although not stated by Musk I am assuming that the 2026 test flights will include a demonstration of the ability to return the astronauts safely to the Earth, as it seems unlikely that the very first test of returning Starship from Mars will occur on a crewed flight. Thus my specific question is what capability must exist by 2026 in order to enable a human landing in 2028.
Because of the statement by Elon Musk, many people seem to feel that while this timeline will possibly slip, it means the capability of sending humans to Mars now exists. Affecting public (and lawmaker) opinion on technical capability like this can have a seismic effect on space policy. So I think it is important to analyze the statement objectively to better understand Musk's assertion that SpaceX now has the technical capability to land people on Mars, or will have it ready to be tested by 2026. Something which is difficult to determine since the actual current technical capability of SpaceX is not fully accessible to the public.
No one, not even Elon Musk claims to be able to predict the future with 100% accuracy, as evidenced by his qualifier "if the (2026) landings go well". However he has clearly implied that SpaceX technology has reached the point that he believes that they are effectively ready to begin human flights to Mars, and that they plan to demonstrate this capability during the next available Mars transfer window. This adds a complication because while some things like EVA suits, radiation shielding and life support can be tested in Earth orbit anytime prior to 2028, the Mars landing and Earth return capability can only be demonstrated during the 2026 window. Thus my question about these specific test flights which will occur two years from now.
Note that I do not consider examples of past timelines by Musk that proved to be inaccurate as evidence for the likelihood of whether or not SpaceX will be able to demonstrate Mars landing and return to Earth in 2026. I am looking only for details of what will need to occur in the 2026 demonstration flights to support the subsequent 2028 human missions.

"the pace of achievement has a somewhat stronger priority over the risk to human life" - I'd argue that once on mars, having more people would make them more likely to survive (more people to do tasks, higher chance someone has a specialized skill that could be surprisingly useful, easier division of labor...)

@StevePemberton If SpaceX agrees with you, something they could do is send 1 starship a few days ahead of the others, giiving the other ships time to abort if it fails (abort might mean go around until you rendezvous with earth again but...)

@StevePemberton I can think of some problems which prevent a landing but work for a landing on Earth. Examples:Something fails, starship doesn't land in exactly the right place, and hits a rock+explodes. Hitting somewhere in an ocean is much easier. Another example:The crew finds out that all the food on base for them is rotten.

You're talking about Musk, a man who is the world's best in selling wishful-thinking, bold-bordering-on-delusional statements to the masses. 2026 or 2028 have no connection to reality, these numbers are in Muskyears. As late as 2017, Musk claimed that Starship was going to fly cargo to Mars by 2022. See how that worked out? (Which is understandable, space is hard!) The core of your question ("what capabilities need to be developed?") is sound, but including "2026" next to it just makes it less of a question and more of a PR move.

@TooTea - The CTO of the world’s dominant space launch company has stated that in 2026 they will demonstrate the ability to land humans on Mars and return them safely to the Earth. As much as I would like to I don’t want to take the easy route of using easily provable examples of prior blustering as an argument for whether Musk's claims of current technical capability are accurate. A serious claim has been made (serious in nature, whether or not serious in intent), but it’s hard to find detailed discussions about it other than the typical polarized opinions with little evidence provided.

@TooTea What do you mean a PR move? Do you seriously think SP works for SpaceX (if so I think their frequent attacks on Musk would get them fired, no?)

@Starship Not really,I should have probably worded that differently. I meant that giving exposure to this kind of blatantly unrealistic claims doesn't really help make SE a neutral source of objective information,and instead it might seem that being mentioned on SE lends some credibility to those claims.

I mean, regardless of how Musk's timelines worked in the past,do people really believe that SpaceX can get a whole two-year round-trip mission to Mars prepared in less than two years, when Starship hasn't even achieved LEO yet?

@TooTea I do for one


Reliable and reusable Starship and Superheavy.
Rapid turn around of Superheavy and tankers.
Orbital re-tanking.
Long term cryogenic propellant storage in 0g followed by engine restart.
EDL (Entry Descent and Landing) on Mars.
ISRU (In situ Resource Utilization propellant production on the surface of Mars.
Long term cryogenic propellant storage on Mars.
Lift-off from Mars.
Return to Earth or Earth orbit from Mars transfer velocity.
Detailed design to allow testing of other key elements such as ECLSS (Environmental Control and Life Support System), radiation protection measures, communications, Mars suits, rovers,
contamination/decontamination measures and ISRU equipment etc.

And a lot more besides depending on your attitude to risk. Elon Musk and NASA have different views on what is acceptable. So that is another thing that will need to be sorted out and clarified.

Is ISRU the only way in 2026 for a Starship to launch back towards Earth with enough delta-v? Is it impossible to send tankers with enough fuel either to the surface or to Mars orbit? Hard to say what Starship payload capacity will be in 2026, seems less likely block 3 and Raptor 3 will be ready in 2026, but the question is about what is possible not what is likely. Also note that point 9 cannot be accomplished before the 2028 launch. Some of the points in 10 aren't  really needed until 2028, good to see what's needed in 2028 also, but for clarity better if listed separately from 2026.

Yes! - acronyms expanded. Is ISRU the only way? Probably not (although I haven't done the calculations so it's an opinion). They could probably muscle it by sending a lot more Starships to Mars with a range of options such as low Mars orbit tankers, small Mars ascent transfer vehicles etc. But I suspect that they will have their work cut out just sending a couple of ships with all of the refilling required. Point 9 might be accomplished by a flight around the Moon followed by an extra propulsive boost (although you are probably right). Point 10 items need to fly in 26 to test them for 28.

I'd like to point out that NASA has no control over what SpaceX does unless they're launching their payloads/astronauts.

@Starship Yes this is true, although IMO it seems likely that the first crewed mission to Mars would carry NASA astronauts. Because any such mission to Mars would be very expensive (even with Starship) and would likely need Government sponsorship of some sort. And any SpaceX mission to Mars without NASA involvement would devastate the image of NASA. So I suspect that something would be worked out, but we shall see...

@Slarty I suspect it won't, because involving NASA will mean SpaceX has to listen to NASA to some extent and be peppered with regulations and rules to the point they can't do anything. Starship currently costs $90 million to build and is estimated to get down to $20 million without reuse. With 100 reuses, it could get as low as 2.4 million. If we releastically assume Starships (with a 2 year turnaround) will only get reused 10 times, that bring my estimate to 2.85 million. But theres also an estimated 4 tanker launches. That brings the cost to 12.45 million.

@Slarty Now keep in mind that this is excluding the cost of whatever stuff are sent to Mars before people come (and the 1 time cost of the stuff only needed for the first trip). But, still, given that an estimate 100 people will go on each mission, that's a cost as low as $124,500 per ticket. That suggests SpaceX could make a huge profit margin...Anyways the point of this was that this would get very profitable very fast without NASA and anyways Musk has a net worth of like 300 billion.

There has been no announcement that NASA is  planning to send any of its astronauts on SpaceX's 2029 Starship human landings on Mars. NASA's current focus is on the 2026 Starship human landings on the Moon.

Some interesting points. May be NASA won't be involved. But if so then NASA will no longer regarded as a leader in space exploration and discovery - just an also ran. May be Elon Musk's claims about Starship reuse and cost will meet expectations, but it hasn't even reached orbit yet so we shall have to wait and see if and when that happens. NASA's current focus may (or may not change under the new administration). There would not be time for a complete start to finish demonstration,  in 2026 but there are a wide range of options and approaches perhaps some could be carried out in parallel?

@Slarty Does anyone seriously regard NASA as a leader in Space Exploration who is reasonably informed on the subject? Outside of building payloads for science, they literally can't do anything remotely useful. Starship has effectively reached orbit (it's quite obvious that it could)

I think a lot of older people do, especially those who can remember the Moon landings and those who don't follow the space program closely. But perhaps you are right. If so, NASA either needs to be split up, shut down or transformed because when the first SpaceX astronaut steps foot on Mars and NASA are asked to comment by the press, talking about SLS is not going to go down well.

The announcement in September 2024 by Elon Musk that SpaceX plans to launch a privately funded human mission to Mars as early as 2028 would seem to be nearly as ambitious as John F. Kennedy’s 1961 goal of landing a man on the Moon by the end of the decade. Especially since Musk's timeline requires that a complete Mars landing and return to Earth test mission demonstrating that a human landing would be safe must be accomplished two years from now in 2026, prior to sending astronauts to Mars in 2028. And unlike the Apollo program which had massive federal funding, as well as the resources of multiple large aerospace and industrial companies, scientific institutions, and governmental agencies including of course NASA, SpaceX appears to be doing this all on its own. While recent political events might at some point change the economic and resources equation, it's unlikely that this would happen soon enough to affect the looming 2026 deadline in an appreciable way. And yet Musk has made it clear in his statement that he believes that this timeline is possible.



Representation (by the author) of a hypothetical Starship landing leg plaque

Realistically, landing astronauts on Mars even by 2033 would be extremely challenging, not only because of the huge technical challenges which have to be overcome, but especially because of the limitation of the Earth-Mars transfer windows, which limits test flights to Mars to approximately every twenty-six months.
The SpaceX rapid iterative design process seems well suited for low Earth orbit launches, and probably also for Moon launches, because other than normal logistics (or regulatory approvals) there is nothing that prevents frequent test flights. In the case of Starship for example there have been six full stack test launches since the first flight in April 2023, with a decreasing amount of time between each test flight:



Starship Full Stack Test Flight
Date
Days Between Flights




1
4/20/2023



2
11/18/2023
212 days


3
3/14/2024
117 days


4
6/6/2024
84 days


5
10/13/2024
129 days


6
11/19/2024
37 days



The amount of iteration and progress that occurred between each of these flights is too much to detail here, but it has been an impressive display of the SpaceX iterative process, especially considering the scale of Starship as the largest rocket in the world, and the scope of doing things that have never been done before, such as tower catches.
Now imagine that each of these Starship test launches had been separated by 700 days. While that seems almost unthinkable for SpaceX, the fact is that the immutable barrier of Mars launch windows creates the equivalent of a two-year FAA delay between launches to Mars, greatly slowing down the iterations between versions other than what can be tested in Earth orbit such as refueling and in-space long term cryogenic storage.
Essentially this forces SpaceX into more of a traditional waterfall method of development, at least for the Mars flights, where they will need to design and analyze and test as much as possible ahead of a flight, to increase the chances that the ships that they build and send to Mars have the highest possibility of a successful outcome, because one small problem that results in test failure will set them back over two years while waiting for the next launch window.
2026, 2028, 2031 - The Learning and Development Period
This makes a human landing even in 2033 extremely challenging, as there are only three launch windows available for testing prior to this – 2026, 2028, and 2031.  During these three launch windows SpaceX would have to test sending Starships to Mars, landing them, refueling them, and returning them safely to Earth. And of course developing other capabilities such as radiation shielding, life support, etc., however those can be tested to some degree in between Mars launch windows. But several important capabilities can only be tested on actual test flights to Mars. Note that while the question is specifically about 2026, the 2033 hypothetical timeline is relevant because it contains all of the same elements that will need to be demonstrated successfully in 2026 using Musk's stated 2028 human landing goal.
2026 - Entry and Atmospheric Testing
Using what we have seen with the Starship test program so far as a template, on a 2033 timeline we could probably expect SpaceX to attempt launching several Starships to Mars in 2026 (which has in fact also been stated by Musk), perhaps each with different design variations to be tested, with the primary goal being to test the controllability of Starship in the Mars atmosphere during entry, as well as testing various thermal protection solutions to determine the type and amounts needed. Similar to the early test flights of Starship, simulated landing with no landing gear would possibly be attempted if any of the test ships made it that far, but landing tests would probably not be a priority during the first launch window.
2028 - Landing Tests
Assuming that the 2026 atmospheric test flights are successful, then in 2028 there would probably be the first actual landing attempts.  Landing on Mars is a huge challenge, harder in many ways than landing on the Moon. Starship will be many times more massive than anything that has landed on Mars before. And it will be using a landing technique that has been tested on Earth, but never on Mars. And never on uneven terrain.
2031 - Refueling, Launch From Mars, Return to Earth
Assuming that the 2028 test landings are successful, then in 2031 there would probably be the first attempts at testing refueling at Mars, launch from Mars, and return to Earth. This would likely involve either ISRU fuel production, or refueling in Mars orbit.  Each would have extreme challenges.  Refueling in Mars orbit means that the landing ships must have enough fuel remaining to launch back into Mars orbit and rendezvous with a fuel depot. And it would likely require an extremely large number of Starships to ferry to Mars orbit the fuel needed for each returning Starship, along with the requisite number of additional Starship launches needed to fuel each of the tanker ships prior to their ferry mission to Mars.  ISRU would be no less challenging, as it requires semi-autonomous robotic capability to extract water ice from the surface, which has to be delivered to an electrolysis system, with the resulting oxygen delivered to storage tanks, and the hydrogen pumped into a Sabatier reactor, with the resulting methane delivered to storage tanks. And then the oxygen and methane has to be pumped from the storage tanks into Starship’s propellant tanks prior to launch, similar to what currently happens at the Boca Chica launch site. There could be other methods used such as outputting the propellants directly into the ship's tanks, but whichever method is used the complexity level will be high.
Looking at all of the things that must be developed and tested in just three Mars transfer window launch opportunities, it could be argued that a 2033 human landing on Mars fits within the definition of “Elon time”, i.e. every development step and test has to go relatively smoothly and with no major problems that would result in requiring additional transfer windows for testing. Considering all of this I think an argument could be made that a 2033 human landing on Mars is wishful thinking.
Massively Compressed Waterfall
However instead of this approach the CEO and Chief Technology Officer of the world’s dominant space launch company has said that SpaceX plans to launch humans to Mars in 2028, which essentially means a highly compressed waterfall design process that would result in the launching of Starships in 2026 which are capable of demonstrating a complete Mars landing and return mission. This means that all of the test flight activities that I have listed above would have to be compressed into one launch window, with no opportunity to draw on experience from previous Starship Mars missions. Since it seems unlikely that any of these capabilities will be tested for the first time on a human mission, this means that during the 2026 window SpaceX will need to successfully demonstrate launch to Mars, landing, refueling, and return to Earth.
Complicating things even further is that for an extended stay mission there would not be time for the 2026 uncrewed ships to return to Earth prior to the launch of the human flights in 2028.  Again assuming that a complete mission will be demonstrated prior to sending astronauts to Mars, this would seem to be physically impossible using chemical rockets. However it might be possible for a short stay mission of about thirty days, which would allow the 2026 ships to return to Earth prior to the 2028 launch window. This seems to eliminate ISRU as a potential refueling method for the 2026 missions, as it seems nearly impossible that the required methane and oxygen production volume could be completed within thirty days.
The actual likelihood of SpaceX achieving all of this by 2026 is a separate question, considering that in some ways it would be the equivalent of NASA pulling off an uncrewed Apollo lunar landing and return demonstration in 1963. And also considering that the Starship program is still currently working on accomplishing basic Starship capabilities such as its first orbital flight with payload, in-space refueling, and the recovery of the spaceship, none of which it now appears will happen until 2025. Along with what was mentioned in a previous answer, it seems clear that an Olympus Mons sized mountain of massive technical challenges would have to be climbed by SpaceX during the next twenty-four months in order for SpaceX to demonstrate a full Mars mission including return to Earth in 2026.

The majority of the challenges of a long duration manned deep space mission can be addressed without actually going to a specific destination, so not all testing is launch window constrained. Still, long duration is not compatible with rapid iterative development.

@JohnDoty - I did mention that. As for iterative design, I was referring specifically to atmospheric controllability, thermal protection, landing, and launch from Mars. Each of these items are major challenges for a Mars mission. They can be modeled and tested to a certain extent, but really benefit from testing at Mars, and ultimately must be validated at Mars. Thus requiring heavy waterfall development for the missions unless you don't mind having a two year delay in between tweaks to the design. Basically for a large portion of the project SpaceX will have to work more like JPL does.

@StevePemberton on r/colonise Mars there was a post from a user who calculated the SpaceX 2028 Mars trip to see if it were possible. The user decided to completely leave out ISRU and instead assumed all the supplies needed would be brought (including the return fuel). It might be of interest to you https://www.reddit.com/r/Colonizemars/comments/1g6cv4t/could_spacex_realistically_send_humans_to_mars_by/

@TheRocketfan - Interesting link. If their calcs are correct then what Musk is effectively saying is “In 2026 we will send four tankers and one uncrewed lander to Mars. In 2028 the lander will launch into Mars orbit where it will be refueled by the four tankers, then it will begin the return to Earth. There will not be enough time for the 2026 ship to return to Earth prior to the crewed launches, so a decision whether to launch the crewed missions will be made using reentry and landing predictions based on the results of the Trans Earth Injection and current propellant levels of the ship.
